# Snapshot count for time interval for each VM in pyvmomi api

Tags: python-3.x, vmware, esxi, vcenter, pyvmomi

Iam trying  to get snapshot information  from python pyvim api.

In powershell  there is Get-Snapshot method where we can collect last 7 days created Vms Snapchat count for every virtual machine connected to vcenter.

Iam not able to find in pyvmomi api similar method which collects Snapchats in time interval.

Can someone  suggest some information??

Comment: Snapchat? Perhaps you meant to write "snapshot" and you phone/computer autocorrected it?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes its snapshot

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Iam connecting  to vcenter and need to rigger few alarms if snapshot  count In last 7 days is crosses the limit. Using pyvmomi  api in python.

Comment: How about this code? https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/snapshot_operations.py#L115-L120